# Update query not working in Java application

Tags: postgresql, jpa

```
public void daoMethod(){

String query="Update tableA set flag='1' where id=? and id2=?";
jdbcTemplate().update(query,id,id2);
}
```

The above method is getting executed without any errors and logs also show no errors, but the
database column flag is not getting updated.
Can anyone suggest a solution, tried to set auto commit false, `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`, PlatformTransactionManager to commit , changed datatype in Database for flag to character, character varying, citext from text , but still not working.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Your question is very Java focused - what happens if you run your query using the psql CLI tool? If there's a problem there, then it's a DBA issue, if not, then it's a JDBC/Java issue and better asked on StackOverflow - I'm voting to close for the time being - if you edit and show that's it's really a DB issue, then I'll vote to reopen - ping me here with @ + my avatar - i.e. Vérace - no space!

Comment: Thanks for putting this on the Java Forum.

Comment: update query is working fine in Database , but from Java application, when the end point is invoked it is not working.

Comment: If you are using Spring boot you could add ```spring.jpa.show-sql=true``` to your application.properties do see which sql are sent to the database.

Comment: Using Spring boot , we have application.yml file , can we include under the Spring attribute., we are not using hibernate either

Comment: jdbctemplate.update() is updating only one row in the table instead of all rows, no errors or exceptions in the logs, can anyone assist, what is the solution, I can retrieve updaterowcount, but need to know why it's only updating only one row.

Comment: how to get the row count from the update statement,  jdbcTemplate().update() is returning an integer, but the integer value is 0, rows updated in the database is shown as 150, what would be the reason or solution for this.